# Qt property system: QVector/QMap

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, serialization, reflection

There in Qt the reflection system which we can use for read/write properties of basic datatypes.

Like the below:

```
int propertyStart = QObject::staticMetaObject.propertyOffset();
for (int i = propertyStart; i < MyObject::staticMetaObject.propertyCount(); ++i)
{
    QMetaProperty property = MyObject::staticMetaObject.property(i);

    QVariant value = 123;  // value to write (QVector/QMap is not supported for QVariant?)

    if (QString(property.name()) == "IntegerPropertyName")
        property.write(instance, value);

}
```

My use case: I need to deserialize the network data (such as JSON or binary) to some QObject-based type with data structure defined by Q_PROPERTies in QObject (data hierarchy).

It can be just basic data types (integer, float, QString) or nested data types (other QObjects) and containers (QVector, QSet and QMap, **element types can be other QObjects also!**)

So, I heard about `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` but unsure how to apply it.

How can I accomplish such type of deserialization with Qt?

Comment: Fixed the `int propertyStart = QObject::staticMetaObject.propertyCount();`. There you should have `.propertyOffset()`.

Comment: Unfortunaly, the Qt not supports container reflection at all.
I hope the Qt team will improve the Qt `Property System`.

Epic Games did it with helper datatypes for each standard container. I think the Qt team must do this similarly.

If I'm wrong, correct me please.

Comment: No one prevents you from trying to serialize vectors and maps with a bit of own technique, though.

Comment: The Qt Property System tied to code generation.
To make cute serialization in Qt I need to get access to this and refactor QVector/QMap inside also. And many others.
Another way is very bad smell code: creating cases for every new datatype that can be serialized...

Comment: Of course some wrapper for those "stubborn" types required. Not directly serializing QVector but somehow like `outStream << adapter(vector)`.